# Which one is right " He is menace to me " or " He is menace for me "?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is right for the following sentence -

Which one is right " He is menace to me " or " He is menace for me " ?

Comment: In the future, consider asking questions like these on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  *Menace* is a noun (and a verb) not an adjective. "He is *a* menace *to* me."

**Edit:** as Lawrence pointed out, if you hired a bodyguard or bought a big vicious dog, he would be a menace *for* you: he would menace other people on your behalf.

Comment: Also valid: "He menaces me."

Comment: Menace can be used as a verb e.g. in my post below `e.g. subject is menacing another subject`

Answer (score 0):

With the zero article before *menace*, you're invoking a figure of speech, that *he* is Menace personified (arguably capitalised in this way as a proper noun).

The first form expresses your opinion of *his* hostility towards you (or possibly towards anyone generally), and the second of *his* hostility on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

The grammatically correct way to put the two would be:

1. He is menacing me `(verb, to menace)`
2. He is a menace `(noun, a menace)`

or

1. He is menacing to me `(verb in present tense, being menacing)`